# How to write and use a custom Laravel 5 Validator to validate multiple other fields values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have fields in a form that are only required IF two other fields are set TO SPECIFIC VALUES. This is not a case of required_with_all.  ITs not if they are set, its if they are set specifically.

Example: **'foo' => 'required_if_all:bar,2,bat,1'**,

I added a service provider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Validator;

class RequiredIfAllProvider extends ServiceProvider {

/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('required_if_all', function($attribute,$value,$parameters){

        // Is required if the list of key/value pairs are matching
        $pairs = [];
        foreach($parameters as $kp => $vp) $pairs[$kp] = $vp;
        foreach($pairs as $kp => $vp) if(\Request::input($kp) != $vp) return false;
        return true;

    });
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

}
```

And I make sure to use the  `App\Providers\RequiredIfAllProvider`; in the top of my custom Request file.

If bar and bat are both set based on the parameters based to the validation, a new error should be added to the error bag.

I have spent quite a bit on this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just look for the login controller. laravel 5 onwards, I think they moved the auth to a 'trait' just add your required values and such there.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with login or auth. The goal is a site-wide available validation rule.

Comment: sorry I was fixated on validation. anyways, in laravel 5.1 you could use traits to apply unique set of functions and variables to a controller. you can add your validation there so you can inject it everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register the service provider in `config\app.php` under `providers`, no need to use it in the request class. ([Docs/Registering Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers#registering-providers))
2. Don't get the other attributes from the `Input` facade! This limits the use of your validator heavily and could lead to weird bugs. The fourth parameter passed to the validation callback is the validator instance. It has a `getData()` method giving you all the data your validator is currently validating.
3. As your rule should also be run on empty values, you need to register it with the `extendImplicit()` method. ([Docs\Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules))

---

Untested example code:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extendImplicit('required_if_all', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        // No further checks required if value is there
        if ($value) {
            return true;
        }

        // Convert $parameters into a named array with the attributes as keys
        $n_pairs = floor(count($parameters)/2);
        $pairs = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n_pairs; $i++) {
            $pairs[$parameters[$i]] = $parameters[$i+1];
        }

        // Check if all pairs match with the input
        $data = $validator->getData();
        foreach ($pairs as $key => $value) {
            if ($data[$key] !== $value) {
                // If at least one pair does not match, the rule is always true
                return true;
            }
        }

        // All pairs match, now $value has to be set
        return !!$value;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best practice would be using a Form Request as explained in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation).

And you can use `required_with_all` and such in validation as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules)

Comment: using L5 not 5.1.  I am also using a custom form request for this.  Required_with_all doesn't work in this case.